# Generate many files with wildcard, then merge into one

Tags: merge, snakemake, wildcard-expansion

I have two rules on my Snakefile: one generates several sets of files using wildcards, the other one merges everything into a single file. This is how I wrote it:

```
chr = range(1,23)

rule generate:
    input:
        og_files = config["tmp"] + '/chr{chr}.bgen',
    output:
        out = multiext(config["tmp"] + '/plink/chr{{chr}}',
                       '.bed', '.bim', '.fam')
    shell:
        """
        plink \
        --bgen {input.og_files} \
        --make-bed \
        --oxford-single-chr \
        --out {config[tmp]}/plink/chr{chr}
        """
rule merge:
    input:
        plink_chr = expand(config["tmp"] + '/plink/chr{chr}.{ext}',
                           chr = chr,
                           ext = ['bed', 'bim', 'fam'])
    output:
        out = multiext(config["tmp"] + '/all',
                       '.bed', '.bim', '.fam')
    shell:
        """
        plink \
        --pmerge-list-dir {config[tmp]}/plink \
        --make-bed \
        --out {config[tmp]}/all
        """
```

Unfortunately, this does not allow me to track the file coming from the first rule to the 2nd rule:

```
$ snakemake -s myfile.smk -c1 -np                                                                           
Building DAG of jobs...                                                                                                                                       
MissingInputException in line 17 of myfile.smk:                            
Missing input files for rule merge: 
[list of all the files made by expand()]
```

What can I use to be able to generate the 22 sets of files with the wildcard `chr` in `generate`, but be able to track them in the input of `merge`? Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rule `generate` I think you don't want to escape the `{chr}` wildcard, otherwise it doesn't get replaced. I.e.:

```
        out = multiext(config["tmp"] + '/plink/chr{{chr}}',
                       '.bed', '.bim', '.fam')
```

should be:

```
        out = multiext(config["tmp"] + '/plink/chr{chr}',
                       '.bed', '.bim', '.fam')
```